# How do I scratch the middle of my back in a car?

Tags: car, comfort

I always seem to get an itch right on the middle of my back when I am driving alone - hence there is nobody to help me with this issue.

How can I relieve this itch in the middle of my back while driving?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***This may be uncomfortable sometimes.***

- Lay a jacket on your seat. This way when you get the urge to scratch you can rub your back on the jacket. The ridges and texture will help alleviate the itching.
- If you have a steady hand while driving you could try using a back scratcher. These are pretty inexpensive.

---

**Additional Info**

[Wikihow.com](http://m.wikihow.com/Scratch-Your-Back)

Answer (score 1):

I find just simply stretching my arms as far as possible (while keeping control of the vehicle) will make the middle of the back more exposed to the seat. Then you can just rub you back up against the chair - hard enough so that it can somewhat satisfy the itchiness.

*Note, this is useless if you're in a leather seated car.*

Comment: There are people who don't stretch this far, and your suggestion is not really a hack

Comment: @s3v3ns I would agree, but seeing as there appears to be no hack, simply answering is ok... (From the meta Lifehacks Manifesto) "You can't always know if a problem needs a life hack before you ask it. So if it turns out that someone's problem also has a "practical" solution, someone should be able to say so."

Comment: A hack(maybe) would be to recommend a stick if you cannot stretch

Comment: @s3v3ns I'm not saying you need to be stretchy and flexible, you just need to extend you arms as far as you can.

Comment: @MrPhooky Like by pushing into the seat of the car harder than usual?

Comment: What if he can not reach the middle of the back. You are assuming he means the lower back where it is easy to reach. What if he means somewhere higher where some people just can not reach. That is my point

Comment: @s3v3ns Well then it is down to him to state that. And I'm pretty sure the whole back can be reached by a car seat...

Comment: **There's nothing wrong with posting non-hacky solutions.** This has been brought up several times, and to quote   @RobertCartaino: "You cannot have a site that insists the best way to drive in a nail is with the back of a shoe."  Stack Exchange is about finding the best solution to a persons problem, and Lifehacks is no exception to this. If  question attracts non-hack solutions which work then that's a problem with the *question*, not the answer. [Shog9 wrote a good post about this here](http://meta.lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/2392/165).

Comment: What he said ^ ;)